# Webpacker:compile freezes on "compile..." on circleci

Tags: webpack, webpacker, circleci-2.0

This is the first time we are trying to run tests with webpacker compiling Vuejs app. The build freezes on the webpacker:compile step and then times out with this message:

```
Too long with no output (exceeded 35m0s)Too long with no output (exceeded 35m0s)
```

Default timeout was 10 minutes, we thought maybe that wasn’t enough and increased it to 35mins, and it still fails. On localhost it takes less than 20 seconds to compile with NODE_ENV=test and RAILS_ENV=test
We use rspec and capybara for tests.

We run webpacker on heroku successfully, although the compile time is long(6-7 minutes), it still finishes. Has anybody had this or similar issues? Pls help to resolve.

**Rails 4.2.10**

**webpacker 4.0.7**

**circleci config:**

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/judgeme/judgeme
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      RACK_ENV: test
      NODE_ENV: test
     #some other variables in here
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.4-node-browsers
    environment: # environment variables for primary container
      BUNDLE_JOBS: 3
      BUNDLE_RETRY: 3
      BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
      PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
      PGUSER: judgeme-test
      RAILS_ENV: test
  - image: circleci/postgres:9.5-alpine-ram # database image
    environment: # environment variables for database
      POSTGRES_USER: judgeme-test
      POSTGRES_DB: judgeme_test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
  - image: redis
  - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.0.1
steps:
  - checkout
  - run: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS

  # Restore bundle cache
  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        # - rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        - rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        # This branch if available
        - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        # Default branch if not
        - v1-dep-master-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        # Any branch if there are none on the default branch - this should be unnecessary if you have your default branch configured correctly
        - v1-dep-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

  - run:
      name: Bundle gems
      command: 'bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle'

  # Store bundle cache
  - save_cache:
      # key: rails-demo-bundle-v2-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      paths:
      # This is a broad list of cache paths to include many possible development environments
      # You can probably delete some of these entries
      - vendor/bundle
      - ~/virtualenvs
      - ~/.bundle

  - run:
      name: Wait for DB
      command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:5432 -timeout 1m
  - run:
      name: Wait for ElasticSearch
      command: dockerize -wait tcp://127.0.0.1:9200/ -timeout 1m

  - run:
      name: Database setup
      command: bundle exec rake db:schema:load --trace

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - yarn-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}

  - run:
      name: Yarn install
      command: yarn install --cache-folder ~/.cache/yarn

    # save yarn cache
  - save_cache:
      key: yarn-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
      paths:
        - ~/.cache/yarn

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - webpack-{{ .Revision }}

  - run:
      name: Compile webpacker assets
      command: bundle exec rake webpacker:compile
      no_output_timeout: 35m

  - save_cache:
      key: webpack-{{ .Revision }}
      paths:
        - /home/circleci/project/public/packs-test/

  - run:
      name: Run rspec with integrations tests at last
      command: |
        bundle exec rspec --profile 10 --format progress \
                          spec/controllers \
                          spec/jobs \
                          spec/mailers \
                          spec/models \
                          spec/policies \
                          spec/queries \
                          spec/services \
                          spec/integrations \
                          spec
      no_output_timeout: 3600s

  # Save test results for timing analysis
  - store_test_results:
      path: test_results
  - store_test_results:
      path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
  # Save artifacts
  - store_artifacts:
      path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
  - store_artifacts:
      path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
```

**webpacker.yml:**

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  resolved_paths: []

  cache_manifest: false

  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .erb
    - .vue
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  check_yarn_integrity: true

  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: false

  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  compile: false

  extract_css: true

  cache_manifest: true
```

Answer (score 2):

Found solution to freezing compiling in erb-loader issues [here](https://github.com/usabilityhub/rails-erb-loader/issues/47). 
There is some problem with erb-loader and spring interaction which causes the freeze. Changing erb-loader config(config/webpack/loaders/erb.js) solves it.
Need to add

```
env:        {
    ...process.env,
    DISABLE_SPRING: 1,
  }
```

to options, so the entire config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.erb$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'rails-erb-loader',
    options: {
      runner: (/^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'ruby ' : '') + 'bin/rails runner',
      env:        {
        ...process.env,
        DISABLE_SPRING: 1,
      },
    }
  }]
}
```